# datatables column header reflect value used to sort

Tags: datatables

I've got [datatables](http://datatables.net) set up with about 10 columns, two of which do customized filtering when clicking the column headers.

I'd like to change the column header to reflect which filter is currently active.

To do it, I think I'll need to set up fnDrawCallback and look at the values returned by table.fnSettings()

My current code, trimmed to its essentials for this question:

```
var table = $('#units').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": (popSearch) ? [[8,"asc"]] : [],
    "aoColumns":[{ "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": false },
        { "asSorting": [ "", "on", "off", "occ", "none" ] },
                null,
                null,
        { "asSorting": [ "", "revised", "new" ] },
                null,
                null,
                { "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": false }
                ],
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": searchString},
    "sAjaxSource": "/system/units/data.php?1.4.3"
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            /* tweak column headers according to the asSorting value */
    }
});
```

The `asSorting` arrays in the `aoColumns` array show the list of different filters that may be applied to the data being fed to datatables.  If the third column header (Status) is clicked, I'd like its text to match what data was sent, (falling back to "status" if the empty string was sent).  The filtering works, fine; I just want the header to reflect the applied filter.

In Datatables `fnDrawCallback` function, how do I know what values were sent for column sorting?

Answer (score 1):

To enable which Column is being Sorted, and visually see it, all you should have to do is add the

```
"bSortClasses": true,
```

To your Data Tables Script. Such as:

```
"aaSorting": (popSearch) ? [[8,"asc"]] : [],
"bSortClasses": true,
...
```

You should see which column, is being used as the sorter. :)

Comment: My question may be unclear; I'm not just looking for the default visual indicator, but I needed to change the headings based on what values were used to sort various columns.  I solved this ages ago and might post the answer later.